# Email validation doesn't work on invalid domain names - FormIT MODX Revo

Tags: forms, modx, modx-revolution, formit

I have a problem with my form validation: when we write email like this - `foo@bar` - the error is not displayed, but form sending also fails. How can I fix it?

```
[[!FormIt?
&hooks=`spam,email,redirect,FormItAutoResponder`
&emailTpl=`emailTplContact`
&emailTo=`my@email.com`
&validate=`email:email:required,
           name:required,
           agree:required`
&redirectTo=`2532`
&fiarTpl=`emailAutoRespond`
&fiarSubject=`Success`
&fiarFromName=`English School`
&fiarFrom=`my@email.com`
&fiarToField=`email`
&fiarReplyTo=`email`
]]

<form method="post" action="[[~[[*id]]]]">
        <label for="name">Name</label><input required="required" type="name" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Your name" value="[[!+fx.name]]">
        [[!+fx.error.name]]
        <label for="email">E-mail </label><input required="required" type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your email" value="[[!+fx.email]]">
        [[!+fx.error.email]]
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="phone">Phone number</label> <input type="text" placeholder="Phone number" id="phone" name="phone" value="[[+fx.phone]]" size=15/>
            <input type="checkbox" name="agree" id="agree"><label for="agree" [[!+fx.agree:FormItIsChecked=`true`]]>I agree</label>
            [[!+fx.error.agree]]</div>
        <button id="join">JOIN</button>
    </form>
```

I found http://bugs.modx.com/issues/4022 here description of this bug and it seems that this issue must be solved - but how? My FormIT version - 2.0.3

Comment: `foo@bar` is technically a valid email address format.

Comment: OK, I agree, but form fails with this address

Comment: You could start by updating FormIt --currently on 2.2.7.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution - create your own custome validator - https://rtfm.modx.com/extras/revo/formit/formit.validators

As example:

```
<?php
if (!filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $validator->addError($key,'Wrong email!');
}
return true;
```